# VPN in cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, command-line, vpn

Is it possible to setup a vpn connection in my cocoa app or from a commandline?
And where should i start if i want to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time Cocoa apps just act as a front end to the command line OpenVPN: http://www.openvpn.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have find a way for running a configurated VPN whit an AppleScript here:

https://superuser.com/questions/358513/start-configured-vpn-from-command-line-osx

that's is a mine code modification:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell current location of network preferences
    try
        set VPN to service "MyVPN" -- your VPN name here
    on error
    return "NOT A CORRECT VPN FOUND ON THIS COMPUTER"
    end try
    if exists VPN then
        connect VPN
    end if

    delay 15

    if current configuration of VPN is connected then
        return "OK"
    else
        return "CONNECTION ERROR"
    end if
end tell
```

If you want you can run that script inside your COCOA project in that way:
[Getting AppleScript return value in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804541/getting-applescript-return-value-in-obj-c)

```
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VPNCONNECTION" ofType:@"scpt"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errors];

    NSLog(@"result = %@",result);
```

You cna find my question here:
[Objective-C start a VPN Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981646/objectiv-c-start-a-vpn-connection)