# Objective-C start a VPN Connection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, vpn

I have found a way using AppleScript and Objective-C...

What i have done is this AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell current location of network preferences
    try
        set VPN to service "MyVPN" -- your VPN name here
    on error
        return "NOT A CORRECT VPN FOUND ON THIS COMPUTER"
    end try
    if exists VPN then
        connect VPN
    end if

    delay 15

    if current configuration of VPN is connected then
        return "OK"
    else
        return "CONNECTION ERROR"
    end if
end tell
```

end tell

And then executed inside my Cocoa project in this way:

```
SString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myScript" ofType:@"scpt"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errors];

    NSLog(@"result = %@",result);
```

I hope that can be useful, but if anyone knows a way to do it all in Objective-C that would be even better!

Thx Again.

These links might be helpful:

https://superuser.com/questions/358513/start-configured-vpn-from-command-line-osx

[Getting AppleScript return value in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804541/getting-applescript-return-value-in-obj-c)